# Adding an Column Populated by an Arbitrary Value in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, union

Basically, I have a query that returns 2 columns:

```
SELECT ACTION_LOG_ID, COMMUNICATIONS_ID
FROM consumer_action_log
WHERE COMM_TYPE_ID=4
```

To every row in the result set for this query, I want to add the value 234 titled Customer_ID. Here was my best attempt:

```
SELECT ACTION_LOG_ID, COMMUNICATIONS_ID
FROM consumer_action_log
WHERE COMM_TYPE_ID=4
UNION 
SELECT CONSUMER_ID,CONSUMER_FIRST_NAME
FROM consumer_profile
WHERE CONSUMER_ID=234;
```

Note: the result of the second half of the query will always be 234. I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 234 AS CONSUMER_ID, ACTION_LOG_ID, COMMUNICATIONS_ID 
  FROM consumer_action_log 
 WHERE COMM_TYPE_ID=4
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to add an extra COLUMN to every row, right? Here's how:

```
SELECT ACTION_LOG_ID, COMMUNICATIONS_ID, 234 'Customer_ID'
FROM consumer_action_log
WHERE COMM_TYPE_ID=4
```

or, alternate syntax

```
SELECT ACTION_LOG_ID, COMMUNICATIONS_ID, 234 AS Customer_ID
FROM consumer_action_log
WHERE COMM_TYPE_ID=4
```

What you tried (`UNION`) adds extra ROWS to your result set, not extra columns.